# Diacritics from a mysql database not displayed correctly with an HTML and PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding, wamp

I have a mysql database (Wamp) which uses latin1_swedish to encode characters (é, è, ...) but for an unknown reason when I display some results from the database (using an HTML page and a PHP page) the diacritics (à, é, è) are not displayed correctly.

I've already tried to change the charset of my webpage (iso 88599-1, utf-8) but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is being outputted instead? of the characters?

Comment: @Luke An exclamation mark inside a diamond.

Comment: i might be way off, but is it to do with you not using htmlentities when you echo out the data?

Comment: @Luke You're right : it works with htmlentities ! Post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo htmlentities($variable_name);

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your connection to mysql db with the

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

command?

There are several ways:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
```

Or, the "best";

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Comment: No, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I edited my answer with explanation - check it out and try different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the encoding on your files (you can do this with notapad++), in your database (you can see this in phpmyadmin), and your database connection (you can check this in your php file that connects to the db).

They should all match

Answer (score 0):

If you know the character encoding that comes in and you know what goes out, you may be able to use iconv: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

For example if the db is iso-8859 and you need utf-8, you call

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text);
```

You can't just change the character set of a table once values are stored, because the data will not be converted. You will have to convert the data using the available MySQL functions. Read more about that at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html.